# Get type of mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to check if a matrix is converted `2GRAY`.

So this code should return `false`

```
cv::Mat myImage; // (rgb)
cout << isMatGray(myImage) << endl;
```

while this code should return `true`

```
cv::Mat myImage; // (rgb)
cv::cvtColor(myImage, myImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);
cout << isMatGray(myImage) << endl;
```

---

My idea was using the .type() call but I'm not really sure how to use this function the right way.

```
static bool isMatGray(cv::Mat image) {
   return ( image.type() == ?? );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the matrix is gray scale (i.e. single channel) with:

```
static bool isMatGray(const cv::Mat& image) {
   return (image.channels() == 1);
}
```